# Angular2 template: how to wrap contents of ngFor with DIV

Tags: templates, angular

I have uncertain count of columns and undefined length of fields. To display them there is this code:

```
<div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let d of fields">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ d.displayName }}</label>
        <span>{{ viewRecord[d.fieldName]}}</span>
    </div>
</div
```

The result is :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title 1</label>
        <span>Text 1....</span>
    </div>
</div
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title 2</label>
        <span>Text 2....</span>
    </div>
</div
```

Is there any possibility to put these two into one container like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title 1</label>
            <span>Text 1....</span>
        </div>
    </div
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title 2</label>
            <span>Text 2....</span>
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

Please notice that I don't know count of fields, so I have to make modulus of 2 from total count of fields to wrap pair of fields into one container. It's obvious that wrapper will be outside of the cycle. I'm stuck :)

Note that **I'm looking for template-driven answer**. If there's not any, I can cope with it. Any JavaScript I can write myself ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use built-in functionality of `*ngFor`, `odd` and `even` items. Iterate items as usual, but show result only when iterating `even` item. And using `index` to access item directly from items.

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let d of fields; let index=index; let odd=odd; let even=even;">
        <div *ngIf="even">
            <div class="form-group" class="col-md-6">
                <label>{{ fields[index].displayName }}</label>
                <span>{{ viewRecord[fields[index].fieldName]}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" class="col-md-6">
                <label>{{ fields[index+1].displayName }}</label>
                <span>{{ viewRecord[fields[index+1].fieldName]}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's definitely not the best solution (since I am defining the same template twice), but should work.

Comment: This can work :)
I'll try to fire it up and write back

Comment: Yes, this is not the best, but, if I add to the second group *ngIf="fields[index+1]", then it'll be enough ;)

Comment: Good! :)..but still, I will think about more elegant way.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Now these fields are not cascading when left one is higher than right one.

Comment: That's a CSS issue isn't it? Try to investigate generated DOM and you should be able to see if classes are in wrong order, then expected result. Maybe this <div class="form-group" class="col-md-6"> is not perfect and form-group should be nested to col-md-6 div?

Comment: It **is** a CSS issue. I could remove floating from the DIVs, but the stylesheet is not mine - didn't wanted to make changes in the biiiiig (500kb) file. It should be rewritten anyway... With jQuery it would be simple - there are lot of EqualHeight scipts I used before. But Angular2 does not like jQuery much. And EqualHeights in simple JavaScript I could not find.

Comment: I analysed your code and came to one conclusion - you're the best! This is most elegant way that cope shortcomings of Angular2 template language. Very original and smart way of thinking. Thanks again, man. You're the best! :)

Comment: Glad to help! :) Did you manage to fix the CSS already? as I pointed with proper div nesting earlier

Comment: No, I told that I don't want to dig the CSS file. For now, your solution is the best ;)